# Sagt noch jemand "ledig"?

Tags: word-choice

In meiner Schulzeit habe ich gelernt, dass "ledig" nicht verheiratet bedeutet. Doch seither kann ich mich nicht erinnern das Wort irgendwo gelesen bzw. gehört zu haben, stattdessen sagen alle "single". Ist das nur meine Beobachtung oder ist das Wort immer noch gebräuchlich?

Comment: Das Wort steht nach wie vor in vielen amtlichen Formularen.

Comment: *ledig* heißt eigentlich mehr als "nicht verheiratet" - Im Prinzip hat es dieselbe Bedeutung wie "ohne", auch wenn das Wort so kaum noch genutzt wird.

Comment: Lediglich im Wort lediglich.

Comment: Ja, die meisten deutschen Sprachinseln bekommen kaum solche Updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache (DWDS) zeigt einen [konstanten Rückgang der Verwendung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ledig) des Wortes seit 1930.

Das ist mit Sicherheit auch dem Rückgang seiner Bedeutungsvielfalt geschuldet (»Er war seiner Pflichten ledig.«, »Der Acker liegt ledig.«, »ein lediges Pferd«, Beispiele von DWDS).

Dazu kommt, dass dem Status, ledig also vor dem Gesetz und der Kirche noch nie verheiratet worden zu sein, in unserer Gesellschaft heutzutage nicht mehr die frühere Bedeutung beigemessen wird.

Wer gerade ohne Partner ist, ist eben Single.
Wer unverheiratet in einer Beziehung lebt, beschreibt sich eher als »vergeben«, »in einer Beziehung« o. ä., nicht aber als »ledig« (obwohl er der Definition nach ledig ist).
Das kreuzt man dann höchstens auf einem Formular an, wenn man die Auswahl zwischen »verheiratet«, »ledig« und »geschieden« hat.

In meinen Umfeld wird der Begriff kaum, und wenn, dann meist scherzhaft gebraucht.

Comment: Zeitgenössische Funde mit Google-News: SZ: "Auch durch den Kauf eines Benziners sei man nicht aller Sorgen ledig, warnt Lottsiepen." B.Z.: "Cansel Kiziltepe ist ledig, ...". Auf Seite 1 aber nur Schweizer Fundstücke, darunter vermehrt eine Fernsehproduktion "Bauer, ledig, sucht...".

Comment: Richtig. Allerdings würde ich nicht so weit gehen zu behaupten dies sage niemand mehr.